# Difference between access token taken from process than from user/pass

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, window

I am trying to understand the difference between 2 supposly identical access tokens.

1. One way to get access token is using OpenProcessToken(). The function returns an access token that can be used to create other processes or to impersonate.
2. Another way (and there are more, but lets focus these two) is to use LogonUser() function that also returns an access token that can be used to create other processes or to impersonate.

The **difference** is that the access token from (1) is valid as long as the process exists, while the access token in (2) is not attached to any process.

So, (1) what exactly do I get from OpenProcessToken()? Not an access token?
(2) Can I "change" the access token from OpenProcessToken() to be "detached" from the process? (i.e. still valid after the process dies)

Comment: (1) - is not true. token is not "attached" to process. process have reference to token, but token (as any kernel object) will be destroyed only when reference count reach 0. so after you open process token - it become valid how minimum you not close it

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you've observed that makes you think the token becomes invalid after the process exits.  Preferably, post demo code.

Answer (score 2):

> access token from (1) is valid as long as the process exists

This is not true.  The token is not "attached" to any process.  Of course this isn't documented, but you can parse the pdb symbols and observe that `struct _TOKEN` doesn't have any links to the `_EPROCESS` object.

As with any kernel object, the token has a reference count, and it will be destroyed when the reference count reaches zero - but until then, it remains valid.  Every `_EPROCESS` has a reference to the token, but not the other way around.  Once you've opened the process token, it will remain valid as long as you keep it open, even if the process that you obtained it from terminates.

This is easy to test: open a token from some process (with the necessary permissions) and then close/terminate the process.  You will find that you can still use the token with `CreateProcessAsUserW` to start a new process.

So no, there is no difference between the two tokens; in both cases you have a handle to a kernel object.

---

Here is demonstration code showing that the token from `OpenProcessToken` remains valid even after the process exits.  We create an instance of notepad, open its token, wait until the process exists, and then attempt (successfully!) to use the token to start a new instance of notepad.

```
void demo()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    // create new process in suspended state
    // path to notepad hardcoded for for simplicity
    if (CreateProcessW(L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0,&si, &pi))
    {
        // open process token with TOKEN_QUERY only
        HANDLE hToken;
        NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcessToken(pi.hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

        // resume process
        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        NtClose(pi.hThread);

        // close notepad
        WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        PostThreadMessage(pi.dwThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

        // wait notepad exit
        ZwWaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, FALSE, 0);

        NtClose(pi.hProcess);

        // try use "invalid" token from died process
        if (0 <= status)
        {
            // we need TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY access for CreateProcessAsUserW
            // we can at begin (in NtOpenProcessToken open it with the necessary access, this is only for demo

            if (0 <= ZwDuplicateObject(NtCurrentProcess(),
                hToken, NtCurrentProcess(), &hToken, 
                TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY, 0, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE))
            {
                if (CreateProcessAsUserW(hToken, L"c:\\windows\\notepad.exe", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
                {
                    NtClose(pi.hThread);
                    NtClose(pi.hProcess);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetLastError();
                }

                NtClose(hToken);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use only "TOKEN_QUERY" it becomes invalid once the process is destroyed. Could be that without TOKEN_DUPLICATE the ref-count doesn't go up?

Comment: @TCS - what you mean under "it becomes invalid" ?

Comment: @TCS - "the ref-count doesn't go up" - of course no. even strange listen this

Comment: What if you try to "create process" without duplicating it first. Just use the token. Why do you have to "duplicate" it first?

Comment: ZwDuplicateObject doesn't duplicate the token, it just opens a new handle to it.  You could probably leave that out, provided you change the code to open the original handle with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - of course `ZwDuplicateObject` only open new handle to same kernel object (`TOKEN` in this case). but this is only demo (but not optimal code) for strange guess "If I use only `TOKEN_QUERY` it becomes invalid once the process is destroyed."  - so I and open at begin only with `TOKEN_QUERY` - in working code need just `OpenProcessToken` with `TOKEN_QUERY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY`